# Is it possible to emulate direct state access?

Tags: opengl

```
GLuint b;
glGenBuffers(1,&b);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,b);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,...);
```

I think this would become

```
GLuint b;
glCreateBuffers(1,&b);
glBufferData(b,...);
```

Now there is no need for the targets like "GL_ARRAY_BUFFER" anymore. But how would I then emulate this < 4.5?

Could I just bind "everything" to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER behind the scenes like this?

```
glBufferDataDSA(GLuint b,...){
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,b);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,...);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
}
```

I mean it shouldn't make a difference to what I bind if I always make sure to set the binding.

Or will I run into problems if I try to emulate DSA like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a correct call:

```
GLuint b;
glCreateBuffers(1,&b);
glBufferData(b,...);
```

`glBufferData()` is not overloaded to take a buffer name argument. There is a new `glNamedBufferData()` call for the DSA case:

```
GLuint b;
glCreateBuffers(1,&b);
glNamedBufferData(b,...);
```

Your replacement with non-DSA looks fine, apart from the obvious side effect that you are already aware of. It will of course change the current `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding. If you don't care about that, the code sequence should be equivalent. There's probably no need to set the binding to 0 at the end, since you lost the previous binding anyway, and will always have to bind a buffer before using it.

In general, I don't think DSA really adds new functionality, so it should be possible to emulate it with non-DSA calls without much trouble. It's just a new set of API entry points for existing functionality, which according to some claims is supposed to be more efficient.

Comment: the biggest pain with emulating DSA is restoring state so non-DSA aware code doesn't break

Comment: @ratchetfreak: I found that using an RAII-like scheme really helps with that. I create a series of objects at the beginning of my fake DSA implementation that encapsulate selector states the function call changes, and when those objects are destroyed (go out of scope) they automatically restore the state. It's slightly less ugly than having to remember to restore it yourself for every possible control path in the DSA function you're trying to implement. DSA is ***finally*** core in GL 4.5, but it'll be years and years before that means it's widely available so these hacks remain necessary :-\